# What's the difference between Narrator Auto and Always?

Tags: storyteller

In the options for Storyteller on Android, Narrator speech can be set to Never, Auto, or Always. Never is straightforward, (the narrator never speaks), but what's the difference between Auto and Always?

[image: Options with narrator set to Auto]